# R solver optimization problem

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r :

```
   buys ges   dif bin
1 22.34  12 10.34   0
2 55.56  12 43.56   0
3 78.33  12 66.33   0
4  9.99  12  2.01   1
..   ..  ..   ..    ..
```

`dif` is just `abs(buys-ges)` and `bin` is an `ifelse` formula that is `1 if dif is <=10` and 0 otherwise.  I'm trying to maximize the sum of the `bin` column by changing the `ges` column.  The constraint is that `ges` is the same for all rows.  I've tried a couple packages but can't figure out maximizing or optimizing.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
buys <- rnorm(1:100)
> buys <- data.frame(a*100)
> buys <- round(abs(a), 2)
> summary(buys)
    a...100             gs          dif              bin      
 Min.   :  0.89   Min.   :15   Min.   :  1.76   Min.   :0.00  
 1st Qu.: 38.29   1st Qu.:15   1st Qu.: 23.29   1st Qu.:0.00  
 Median : 72.89   Median :15   Median : 57.88   Median :0.00  
 Mean   : 83.91   Mean   :15   Mean   : 70.52   Mean   :0.13  
 3rd Qu.:123.50   3rd Qu.:15   3rd Qu.:108.50   3rd Qu.:0.00  
 Max.   :269.11   Max.   :15   Max.   :254.11   Max.   :1.00  
> gs1 <- 5
> buys$gs <- gs1
> buys$dif <- abs(buys[,1]  - buys$gs)
> buys$bin <- ifelse(buys$dif<=10,1,0)
> colnames(buys) <- c("buys","gs","dif","bin")
> head(buys)
    buys gs    dif bin
1   7.48  5   2.48   1
2  79.08  5  74.08   0
3 139.22  5 134.22   0
4  41.60  5  36.60   0
5  38.35  5  33.35   0
6 157.72  5 152.72   0
> sum(buys$bin)
[1] 10
> num_buys=function(x)
+ {
+   return(length(buys$buys[buys$buys>=x-10 | buys$buys<=x+10]))
+ }
> ans2 <- optimize(f=num_buys,interval=c(min(buys$buys),max(buys$buys)),maximum=TRUE)
> 
> 
> ans2 
$maximum
[1] 269.1099

$objective
[1] 100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since values of `bin` are either 0 or 1, for a given value of `ges`, we're really just counting the number of elements in `buys` that are in the interval `[ges-10,ges+10]`.  Visually, one could imagine "sliding" the interval `[ges-10,ges+10]` starting at `ges=min(buys)` and ending at `ges=max(buys)` and counting the number of entries of `buys` that are in the interval as the value of a function.  In particular:

```
num_buys=function(x)
{
  return(length(buys[buys>=x-10 & buys<=x+10]))
}
```

With that, we can use `optimize` to find a maximum:

```
optimize(f=num_buys,interval=c(min(buys),max(buys)),maximum=TRUE)
```

As an example:

```
> buys=rnorm(10000,mean=50,sd=10)
> summary(buys)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
  11.38   43.22   50.01   50.06   56.93   92.76
> num_buys=function(x){return(length(buys[buys<=x+10 & buys>=x-10]))}
> optimize(f=num_buys,interval=c(min(buys),max(buys)),maximum=TRUE)
$maximum
[1] 50.16788

$objective
[1] 6808
```

So, in this case, a maximum value of `sum(bin)` would be 6808, and this maximum would occur when `ges=50.16788`.  Of course, this makes perfect sense, since about 68% of the values should occur within 10 units of 50 (normal distribution and all that).  :D

Comment: I'm doubtful, this df is just a sample.  If there are 50 buys at 15.00 you would not maximize the sum of bin by using anything near max(buy).

Comment: If `ges=max(buy)`, then `max(dif)=0<=10`, therefore `bin==1` for each row and `sum(bin)` is thus maximal.

Comment: you're correct i wrote it wrong. Its supposed to be abs(buys-ges).  Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to take on the data I'm using.  I added code above.  Am I missing something.  I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Careful, the return value for `num_buys` is `length(buys$buys[buys$buys>=x-10 & buys$buys<=x+10])` (I made the same typo myself before I caught it).